# Where copy Extjs 6.0 new `ux` classes?

Tags: extjs6

I'm developing web application using Extjs 6.0.1. I developed an class as follow:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.main.Me', {
   extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
   xtype: 'ud_mf',
   .
   .
   .
});
```

Now I want to publish it as `ux`. In Extjs 6.0.0 I don't know where direction copy my class. My workspace direction is as follow:

```
.sencha
Admin
build
ext
packages
workspace.json
```

What do I do?

Comment: Where is your app.js located? You need to wrap app.js (which will call the viewport) inside an index.html. A;so please clarify the question. I am moving on the assumption that you are trying to display the panel

Comment: I need to use this class in other application too, and I don't want to add in all of them.

Comment: You could create a package with all your shared classes, or create a folder in your workspace with his own namespace and add that folder to your app using Ext.Loader object (paths).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a Folder named Ux and this in root directory
2. Add all code there with namespace Ux
3. Add this Folder in app.json in this code

   ```
   "classpath": [
   "app",
   "Ux", // this is your folder
   "${toolkit.name}/src"
   ],
   ```
4. In app.js file add in requires like 'Ux.*'
5. Build your project and run

Comment: It's true. But when I build the project, it error as [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dVGGO.png)

Comment: I have similar problem.