# Extjs projects binding at runtime

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

I have three different Extjs projects, all the three using MVC architecture. Out of these three one is going to be common to the other two projects. I would want the common project to be controlling and deciding which project to be loaded. But however I also want to separate the project codes and not have them binded together in a single project. is it possible ? if so how ?

Change:

In Simple Words how can i access few js files in extjs which is not inside the app folder.

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979842/where-copy-extjs-6-0-new-ux-classes/34013551#34013551

Comment: Thanks Mohit. Got it done.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Paths{} attribute inside Ext.loader to set a different path apart from the app path to access files outside app folder. The appFolder attribute of app.js  is set to app by default. You can also change that to map a different app path. You can verify these in Sencha Docs.